# System.TimeSpan to something I can use in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm getting a bunch of information from a web server with SOAP and NSXMLParser, and one of the properties I'm getting is time for when a kid is being picked up...

e.g. a response would be: PT15H

In the documentation it's called: System.TimeSpan pickUpTime

Now, the other properties includes stuff like integers, strings and booleans and I just save them with e.g.

```
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a:LastName"])
{
    aParent.lastName = currentElementValue;
}
```

What do I do with PickUpTime? I need to get the time and show it in a label in a clean manner, like 15:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to just use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString to remove the letters, since I know that I will always get certain letters... then I can convert it into a NSDate with with the format HH:mm

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSDateFormatter and give it the proper structure of the strings you are getting. This way it can be converted into an NSDate object for your use, i.e. displaying it as "15:00" and such.

Comment: The problem is that I am getting it as PT15H... had it just been 15, it would be easy enough to convert to NSDate, but I need to somehow strip the PT and H, and also, it won't always be PT15H, it might be PT15H30M.... so perhaps remove the occurences of PT and H and M? Then be left with e.g 15 or 1530 and then convert this... or is there another way?

Comment: The only way to do this in a generic way is to figure out exactly the format in which the data is being received. Once you know the format, you can use string manipulation (available with NSDateFormatter's format patterns) to extract the data you need. Check this link out: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns